# JQuery sortable 2 flows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have some UI representing one warehouse and some shops.

I have to drag&drop from warehouse to shops, but I should not be able to drag&drop from shop to warehouse and from shop to shop.

How can I set up classes / IDs to enforce this behavior?

I tried with:

```
    $('.sender, #receiver2,#receiver1').sortable({
        connectWith: $('#receiver2,#receiver1').not(this),
    }).disableSelection();
```

where sender is the warehouse and receivers are the shops but I can still drag&drop from shop to shop.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must initiate `.sortable()` separately for each time you want to use `connectWith()`, since `connectWith()` is one-way only. By putting all in same sortable, like you've done, you've enabled one-way from all 3 to both #receiver2 and #receiver1.

Try to separate:

```
$('.sender').sortable({
    connectWith: $('#receiver2,#receiver1')
}).disableSelection(); 
// This one allows .sender items into #receiver2 or .sender items into #receiver1

$('#receiver2,#receiver1').sortable().disableSelection(); 
// This one enables sortable on both, but does not allow #receiver2 or #receiver1 items to leave
```

See working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/w5wdxu9s/1/